# Laravel: creating eloquent scope

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, eloquent

Hey fellow developers,

I am experimenting a tad with eloquent and ran into some troubles.
My token table looks like this now:

```
Table Token
email (VARCHAR 255)
token (VARCHAR 255)
expires (VARCHAR 255)  // this should probably be int.. 
created_at timestamp
```

in my Token model I am building a scope to retrieve all expired tokens

```
public function scopeExpired($query)
{
    return $query->where('created_at', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-   ('expires'*60)));
}
```

This almost does the trick, but its ignoring the ('expires'*60). if I were to replace 'expires' by a number, lets say 30, it works perfectly.

My question basically comes down to this: How can I use the value of the corresponding row of the expires column?

Any assistence is much appreciated!

Regards,
Pwnball

Comment: EDIT: actually that doesn't look like what you wanted, sorry. I think there's no other solution than to do two queries, a first one to get the value of `expires` and a second one to get the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the problem! I did not manage to get the value of the corresponding column, but I figured it would be smart to store the expire moments of tokens in the config.

Now I'm using this code to define the scope and it works like a charm!
I removed the 'expires' column from the token table and replaced it with a:

```
type varchar 50
```

Seeing as I know what type of token I am using at every certain point in my code, this solves the dilemma and results in easier-to-maintain code! win-win!

```
public function scopeExpired($query, $type)
{
    $expires = Config::get('app.tokenExpiration.'.$type, 30);
    return $query->where('created_at', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-($expires*60)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your MySQL problem (PostreSQL would be a bit easier, other engines accordingly):

```
public function scopeExpired($query)
{
  return $query->where('created_at', '<', 
     DB::raw('timestampadd(hour, -expires, now())'
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `whereRaw()` method of the query builder to write raw SQL i.e.

```
return $query->whereRaw("`created_at` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `expires` MINUTE)");
```

MySQL 3.23+